# Python ImportError when building exe

Tags: python, module

I have a python code which i'm converting into exe

The code is working fine in development when i'm running code in terminal

This error is coming when i'm opening the exe

[image: error]

My script modules

```
  from tkinter import *
  import tkinter as tk
  from PIL import ImageTk, Image
  from tkinter import messagebox
  import pymysql
  import time
  import pyautogui
  import datetime
  from datetime import datetime as dt
  from datetime import datetime as dt1
  import win32gui
  import psutil
  import os
  import requests
  import win32process
  import operator
  import random, string
  import threading
  import sys
  import os.path
  from ctypes import Structure, windll, c_uint, sizeof, byref
  from tkinter import messagebox
  from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
  import logging
```

Possible error is comng from here i think - `from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener`

Comment: first run it in console/terminal to see error messages.

Comment: there are many question with problem in PyInstaller and usually problem is the same: Python wasn't create to build .exe and program like Pyinstaller may have problem to find all needed Python modules and C/C++ libraries - and you have to add them manually to file `.spec` - you should find more in PyInstaller documentation. There are pages wiht name like `Using Spec FIle` and `What to do when happend something wrong`

Answer (score 1):

Try build exe this way:

install pyinstaller: `pip install pyinstaller`

Open cdm ->  navigate to folder -> enter following command:

`pyinstaller.exe --onefile --icon=myicon.ico --windowed app.py`

--onefile : create only .exe in one file not in folder with many files

--icon:  if you have icon you want to use for .exe file

--windowed: to open windowed mode.

Comment: it's working but the way i'm creating a exe is also giving me a msi file so i will need that way, can you solve this ImportError??

Comment: Try to use auto-py-to-exe. Auto-py-to-exe have GUI and advanced settings and maybe you will be able to configure what you need.  [Link to instructions](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-easily-convert-a-python-script-to-an-executable-file-exe-4966e253c7e9).